# When the Earth suddenly stops pulling

Tags: gravity, earth, causality, information

Let's say the Earth stops attracting objects to itself all of a sudden. So, I was wondering what would happen to a person standing on the surface of the Earth? (Neglect the effect of the rotation of Earth.)

Since the speed of information travel is finite (speed of light), the fact that the person is no longer pushing down on the ground takes, however infinitesimally small, time to reach the ground. In the mean, the time the ground is still experiencing the weight of the person and as a result, applies a force equal in magnitude but opposite in direction, thus, causing them to go up.

I know the effect will be really really tiny, but my point is that the person goes up.
Am I correct?

Comment: You can make this thought experiment work without magically turning off gravity. Just put the scientist on a rocket accelerating at $g$ then turn off the rocket. If you want planetary scales, just make it a *really long* rocket.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to worry about the speed of light, just the speed of sound.

Real life objects aren't *perfectly* rigid.  There is no perfectly rigid body in existence.  Everything bends and flexes.  The ground flexes, and your feet and/or shoes flex.  When gravity lets go, all of these flexed bodies behave like little springs.  This information travels at the speed of sound (in the medium it is traveling in).  There will be a very minor shock wave, then all of these flexed entities will act like springs and push away.

For a visual of exactly what this can look like, consider the [Spring Paradox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cg73j3QYRJc).  It's a pretty complicated scenario, compared to our turning off gravity, but it shows how some of these objects behave in unintuitive ways.

Comment: Let's say the person and the ground they are standing on, are assumed to be perfectly rigid. Will they still push away?

Comment: @AyushPadhy In that extremely idealized case, with a perfectly rigid body and perfectly rigid Earth, and the Earth is not rotating, they would not push away.  If you do the free body diagram after gravity turns off, you will see that there are no forces pushing on either the person nor the Earth.  The sum of the forces is 0, so the acceleration is 0.  So they'd just hover there, in contact but feeling no force.

Comment: But if the Sun were to disappear, the Earth would still feel an attraction for 8min and 19sec. So, shouldn't the ground, too feel the weight after it suddenly disappears?

Comment: @AyushPadhy There would be an effect there yes.  However, bringing that issue up points me to a fundamental issue I missed the first time.  The concept of an extended "rigid body" is actually at odds with relativity.  There's plenty of paradoxes which arise (such as involving trying to fit a ladder inside a barn that's too small for it), and all of them are resolved by realizing that in a relativistic environment an object simply cannot be perfectly rigid.  It's a mathematical impossibility.